# PHP foreach object error

Tags: php, foreach

I used a POST method later I want to add POST request to a variable but I get an error. Why I get object error?

**Error code**

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

**POST data**

```
array(16) { ["lat"]=> string(15) "41.008550564147" ["lng"]=> string(15) "28.978239484058" ["time"]=> string(1) "6" ["type"]=> string(6) "status" ["status"]=> string(0) "" ["category"]=> string(0) "" ["subCategory"]=> string(0) "" ["room"]=> string(0) "" ["buildingAge"]=> string(0) "" ["sfloor"]=> string(0) "" ["floor"]=> string(0) "" ["square"]=> string(0) "" ["price"]=> string(0) "" ["currency"]=> string(0) "" ["value"]=> string(0) "" ["feedback"]=> string(0) "" }
```

PHP code

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $params .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
    }
    echo $params;
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: isn't $params previously defined as CLASS? Try add $params = ""; before foreach

Comment: Thanks http_build_query worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead.

```
echo http_build_query($_POST);
```